# HTML encoding issue in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, encoding, xss, code-injection

I have a literal control being used to display HTML coming from DB. I did face some XSS issues and implemented Anti-XSS Security Runtime Engine (SRE) to automatically encode all html markup. e.g.

DB : `<p align="center"></p>`

Anti-XSS encodes it as :

```
&#60;p align&#61;&#34;center&#34;&#62;&#160;&#60;&#47;p&#62
```

However, when I am setting text property of literal content from code behind, I was expecting that the literal control will DECODE the proper html and display the rendered version. Instead, it is showing the ENCODED version.

Thus literal control displays - `<p align="center"></p>` postrender. I understand it is Anti-xss in action but how can I get the literal control to show the rendered HTML instead of markup?

```
ASPX - <asp:Literal ID="ltPageContent" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
Code behind on page load - ltPageContent.Text = getPageContent("home")'Gets HTML from DB
```

Am I missing something simple here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without considering XSS risks, you may forget LiteralControl here and use inline codes instead:

ASPX:

```
<%= Server.HtmlDecode(YOUR_STRING) %>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer not to have any code in aspx. Any solution at code-behind?

Comment: well, you need a server-side html control as your container and set your html string to its InnerHtml property. For example, put a <div id="container" runat="server"></div> in your aspx page, and then the behind codes could be "container.InnerHtml = Server.HtmlDecode(YOUR_STRING); "

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the "Mode" property with a value of "PassThrough":

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltPageContent" runat="server" Text="Html Here" 
             Mode="PassThrough" />
```

I do advise to check for XSS before data is passed here though.