# literal control showing character encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem displaying html entities in a literal control in asp.net.

Before I pass my content to a literal control I encode the characters e.g. `£` to `&pound;` but when it gets displayed in the page it displays `&pound;` instead of `£`. I checked the source and it is not encoding the html entity e.g. `&amppound;` but displaying it as plain text.

I have tried removing the `htmlencode` at the backend and adding `mode="encode"` on the literal control but I get the same results.

Does anyone know why this happens?

I know I can use a label control but surely theres a better way?  I do not like the html format literal control gives.

Comment: The Literal is not change anything - you have some other mistake on your code.

Answer (score 1):

Given a literal, lt, you should not HtmlEncode, and set

```
lt.Mode = LiteralMode.PassThrough;
lt.Text = "&pound";
```

or

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lt" Mode="PassThrough">&pound;</asp:Literal>
```

hope this will help

Comment: This does not work. I did a response write and it does display the characters £ and & without the encoding. Which is what was expecting. This is to test that the characters are not already encoded so I am not double encoding. I set mode to passthrough with the backend htmlencode and without. Whatever I pass through just gets treated as plain text.

Comment: @JamesAndrewSmith what happens if you just copy paste in your markup the above asp:literal markup containing &pound;  ?

Comment: The characters get encoded to the respresented value. So &pound; will be £ but through literal it shows it as &pound;.

Comment: @JamesAndrewSmith checked that no anti XSS involved ? like http://stackoverflow.com/q/7695148/1236044